# Trigger to INSERT a table after INSERT on another table, and Participation Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Employees table and a table for newly hired employees called NewHires. Whenever a new employee is added to the Employees table, specific columns from the Employees table will be added to the NewHires table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hiretrig
AFTER INSERT ON Employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NewHires VALUES(Employees.empno, Employees.lname, Employees.hiredate);
END;
/
```

I think that is right, except I'm not sure if those parameters are valid.

I also have to enforce a participation constraint. Every new hire must attend orientation and after they attended orientation they will be removed from the NewHires table.

Comment: You need to use the :NEW.<fieldname> to reference the record context in the trigger.  This probably did not compile.

Comment: Given that you have a HIREDATE field could you not make your NewHires table a view instead, using something similar to `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NEWHIRES AS SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TRUNC(HIREDATE) > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY`?

Comment: Put a Flag for orientation and set the flag to Y or N

Comment: Add a field called `ATTENDED_ORIENTATION` to EMPLOYEES, and constrain it to have values of 'Y' or 'N'.  Then the NEWHIRES view becomes `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NEWHIRES AS SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE ATTENDED_ORIENTATION = 'N'`  Share and enjoy.